# Which number does not fit: 17, 12, 108, 9?

Tags: odd-one-out

When taking an IQ test, the set of numbers given is:

> 17, 12, 108, 9.

You are supposed to work out which number does not fit. I have earmarked 17 as the incorrect number for two different reasons: it's the only number not divisible by 3, and it's the only number not divisible by another number in the sequence (i.e. 108÷12=9) - but the test keeps saying that's not the correct answer.

Please help me determine which number does not fit, and why.

Comment: What is the question exactly? To choose the odd one out among these numbers? Is it just an unordered set of numbers, or a sequence where the order is important?

Answer (score 2):

As @Randal'Thor mentioned in the comments, it's not fully clear whether this is simply a set of numbers or really a sequence where order matters.
Since it is not asked for the next number, this looks to me more like a simple "odd one out". For me there is no "obvious" solution and I am sure you could think of many more reasons why one number is the "odd one out".

17:

> - it is the only prime number

> - it's the only number with an even cross sum

12:

> - the last digits are increasing 7,8,9 but the 2 of 12 doesn't fit

108:

> - as @IlCorsaroNero mentioned it's the only number increasing the otherwise falling sequence

9:

> - because it is the only number which doesn't start with 1

Comment: In other words, odd-one-out puzzles with just a bunch of numbers are a bad puzzle/ question format in general. Any answer is correct and this just becomes a 'guess what I am thinking' puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

For me the incorrect number is :

> 108  because the number are decrease but 108 is the only number the increase the sequence.